# My rails app isn't working in heroku

Tags: logging, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new on rails. I have an app working perfect in my local hots, I uploaded to Heroku but when I got to the site, I got this message.

> The page you were looking for doesn't exist.

Here are my logs, and I did migrate the database

```
   2014-03-29T03:25:11.118772+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-   4.0.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
2014-03-29T03:25:11.118772+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
2014-03-29T03:25:11.119030+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2014-03-29T03:25:11.119030+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2014-03-29T03:25:11.119030+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
2014-03-29T03:25:11.118772+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
2014-03-29T03:25:11.119030+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2014-03-29T03:25:11.126471+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=eco-fuel.herokuapp.com request_id=ec266334-a487-40ea-9559-af650f0d65de fwd="200.83.101.175" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=223ms status=404 bytes=1616
2014-03-29T03:25:11.119211+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2014-03-29T03:25:11.119030+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
2014-03-29T03:25:11.119211+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
2014-03-29T03:25:11.119773+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2014-03-29T03:25:11.119773+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
2014-03-29T03:25:11.119030+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
2014-03-29T03:25:11.119030+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2014-03-29T03:25:11.119211+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"):
2014-03-29T03:25:11.119030+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
2014-03-29T03:25:11.118772+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2014-03-29T03:25:11.119966+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
2014-03-29T03:25:11.119211+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2014-03-29T03:25:11.119211+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-03-29T03:25:11.119966+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
2014-03-29T03:25:11.119211+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-03-29T03:25:11.119211+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2014-03-29T03:25:11.119773+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
2014-03-29T03:25:11.119211+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2014-03-29T03:25:11.119773+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2014-03-29T03:25:11.119030+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
2014-03-29T03:25:11.119966+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2014-03-29T03:25:11.119966+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
2014-03-29T03:25:11.119211+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
2014-03-29T03:25:11.119773+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2014-03-29T03:25:11.119773+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
2014-03-29T03:25:11.119966+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2014-03-29T03:25:11.119773+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2014-03-29T03:25:11.119773+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gem
s/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
2014-03-29T03:25:11.119966+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2014-03-29T03:25:11.119211+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-03-29T03:25:11.119773+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
2014-03-29T03:25:11.119773+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2014-03-29T03:25:11.119966+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
2014-03-29T03:25:11.119966+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2014-03-29T03:25:11.119966+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2014-03-29T03:25:11.119966+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
2014-03-29T03:25:11.120299+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-03-29T03:25:11.120299+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-03-29T03:27:00.880069+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 200.83.101.175 at 2014-03-29 03:27:00 +0000
2014-03-29T03:27:00.880069+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 200.83.101.175 at 2014-03-29 03:27:00 +0000
2014-03-29T03:27:00.883455+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-03-29T03:27:00.883455+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"):
2014-03-29T03:27:00.883455+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2014-03-29T03:27:00.883455+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
2014-03-29T03:27:00.883455+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
2014-03-29T03:27:00.883455+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
2014-03-29T03:27:00.883668+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2014-03-29T03:27:00.883668+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
2014-03-29T03:27:00.883668+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2014-03-29T03:27:00.883668+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
2014-03-29T03:27:00.883455+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2014-03-29T03:27:00.883668+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
2014-03-29T03:27:00.883668+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
2014-03-29T03:27:00.883668+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2014-03-29T03:27:00.883455+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2014-03-29T03:27:00.883455+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
2014-03-29T03:27:00.883668+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2014-03-29T03:27:00.883668+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2014-03-29T03:27:00.884003+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
2014-03-29T03:27:00.884003+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2014-03-29T03:27:00.883668+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
2014-03-29T03:27:00.884003+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-03-29T03:27:00.884003+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-03-29T03:27:00.884003+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-03-29T03:27:00.884003+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
2014-03-29T03:27:00.884003+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2014-03-29T03:27:00.884003+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2014-03-29T03:27:00.884664+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2014-03-29T03:27:00.884664+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
2014-03-29T03:27:00.884664+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
2014-03-29T03:27:00.884664+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2014-03-29T03:27:00.883455+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
2014-03-29T03:27:00.884003+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"):
2014-03-29T03:27:00.884664+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
2014-03-29T03:27:00.884664+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2014-03-29T03:27:00.884664+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2014-03-29T03:27:00.884003+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2014-03-29T03:27:00.884664+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
2014-03-29T03:27:00.884939+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
2014-03-29T03:27:00.884939+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
2014-03-29T03:27:00.884939+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
2014-03-29T03:27:00.884939+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2014-03-29T03:27:00.884939+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
2014-03-29T03:27:00.884664+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
2014-03-29T03:27:00.884939+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2014-03-29T03:27:00.884939+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
2014-03-29T03:27:00.885275+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-03-29T03:27:00.884664+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2014-03-29T03:27:00.884939+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2014-03-29T03:27:00.884939+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2014-03-29T03:27:00.885275+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2014-03-29T03:27:00.885275+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-03-29T03:27:00.904455+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=eco-fuel.herokuapp.com request_id=7402c5cd-ce50-4d0a-88a0-198e46fc2b03 fwd="200.83.101.175" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=28ms status=404 bytes=1616
```

I can't figure out what is wrong, someone can help me please?

Comment: Can you post your `config/routes.rb`?  Do you have a `root :to => 'welcome#index'` or something similar to handle the GET request for `/`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your browser error message and your log both indicates the same thing.

```
2014-03-29T03:27:00.883455+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"):
```

This means that you are trying to go to "/" while you have not set the route "/". You have to set that by specifying the following line in your config/routes.rb.

```
root :to => 'home#index'
```

'home#index' is an arbitrary value. You can set it whatever controller method you want the homepage to use. 'home' refers to the controller while 'index' refers to the method name.

Comment: THANK YOU, that was it, I can't vote up because I don't the reputation. But thnaks

Comment: Glad that it worked. Can you mark this as an answer?